# Что требуется передать в запрос WHERE id='$param' чтобы условие не сработало

Tags: php, mysql

Есть форма с 5-ю полями, поиск осуществляется по этим полям. Но пользователь не обязательно доложен заполнять все поля. Так вот вопрос, как исключить переменные из запроса которые не используются.

Вот сам запрос

```
$STH = $DBH->query("SELECT * FROM `clients` WHERE fio LIKE '%$srch_fio%' and id='$id' and  phone LIKE '%$srch_phone%'  ORDER BY call_date DESC");
```

Так вот если в LIKE передавать false то эти параметры не учитываются при поиске, но если в id='' и подобное передавать false, то это учитывается и ничего не находит. Не искать же id  и другие int, varchar поля c помощью LIKE.

Пытался формировать поля динамически, но тоже не особо вышло, AND не получается вставить правильно

```
    if (!empty($srch_params['id'])) {
    $id = "id = '".$srch_params['id']."' ";
    } else { $id ='';}

     //phone_m LIKE '%$phone%'
    if (!empty($srch_params['fio'])) {
    $fio = "AND fio LIKE '%".$srch_params['fio']."%' ";
    } else { $fio ='';}

    if (!empty($srch_params['phone'])) {
        $phone = "AND phone_m LIKE '%".$srch_params['phone']."%' ";
    } else { $phone ='';}

    $sqla = $id.$fio.$phone;
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, то что нужно. Не догадался сам ))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Просто не надо передавать эти параметры в запрос, вот и всё.

Код на [ideone.com](http://ideone.com/8WvmXT)

P.S.: прочитайте про функцию [implode()](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.implode.php), иногда очень полезная.

Answer (score 0):

Это все здорово, но если бы использовали ORM/ActiveRecord, получили бы такие фильтры для выборок сразу http://www.phpactiverecord.org/projects/main/wiki/Finders